# How to deal with null values in large data using Python

Tags: python, imputation, isnull, data-preprocessing

I have data with approx 1500 columns (features) and 900 rows of data. I am using this to delete values having less than 80% mean value

```
df1 = df.columns[df.isnull().mean() < .8]
```

But still, my remaining dataset contains columns containing having approx 6000  Null values. What would be the best method to use to remove null values? Please guide. And would it be useful to impute values in such a large amount of null valueS? And I have to remove null values at what threshold? which one is best? For example I have features with 100 250 1500 2000 3500 4000 6000 missing values. need your guideline please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for col in df.columns:
    df = df[~pd.isnull(df[col])]
```

Comment: this will drop all columns with null values . i dont think its good solution ??

Comment: For which column you want to drop??

Comment: ofcourse its not logical to drop column with only 10 or 1 value we can impute values there ..its not dependent on my wish to drop